# ...using a comma with a phrase starting with the word 'that'

Tags: commas, syntactic-analysis

Should there be a comma before or after the word 'that' in the sample I grabbed from a draft letter written by the Contracts Dept of a company I do work with:

> Pursuant to an internal restructuring, to better serve our customers, Company X anticipates that, on or about July 1, 2017...

Alternatively, should the comma be placed before the 'that':

> Pursuant to an internal restructuring, to better serve our customers, Company X anticipates, that on or about July 1, 2017...

Comment: You completely misunderstand the role of the comma.  In the first example the commas (there are two of them, if you look beyond the "...") set off a *parenthetical phrase*.  In the second example the comma is just meaningless noise.  In neither case is the presence of "that" of any significance, beyond the usual syntax and semantics.

Answer (score 0):

I would say remove the comma altogether. Consider something like the following:

> "Pursuant to an internal restructuring to better serve our customers, Company X anticipates that (on July 1, 2017) ..."

Another option might be:

> "Pursuant to an internal restructuring to better serve our customers, on July 1, 2017, Company X anticipates that..."

Finally, I would add that I don't much care for the wordiness of the sentence. You might want to consider breaking it up a bit. It's a little exhausting to read. Good luck!